# ldap users cannot log in

Tags: ldap, directory-utility

I have created an ldap server (hosted externally with a domain name) on a ubuntu 18.04 machine with openLDAP. I configured linux machines to allow my users to connect using ldap and it works as expected (the user can log-in on the machine, and it creates a new home directory).

However on mac, I can list my users in the Directory Utility :
[image: active directory list]

And I can get my user information (with his group declared in ldap)

```
bash$ id -p hlarget
    uid hlarget
    groups  sysadmin everyone netaccounts com.apple.sharepoint.group.1
```

But when I try to login as the admin user to edit my directory, I have a 2100 error. And when I try to log using `ssh hlarget@localhost`, or even in session manager, I cannot :

```
    failed CRAM-MD5 authentication for authzid - 'dn:cn=hlarget+o=example+ou=users,ou=users,dc=example,dc=com' authcid - 'hlarget' error 49
```

I'm pretty sure it's an encryption error (I use `ssha` encryption for my UserPassword). How can i figure out what the problem is? And how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem using this script

```
for m in CRAM-MD5 DIGEST-MD5 LOGIN NTLM PLAIN; do
  /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "add ':module options:ldap:Denied SASL Methods:' string $m" /Library/Preferences/OpenDirectory/Configurations/LDAPv3/ldap.foo.fr.plist
done
```

I'm pretty sure it's not the best answer but still, it do the trick and now I can log in.